# Next 13 tailwind hydration failure

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Im trying to use useState in page.tsx file using "use client", but there are Hydration errors when I add "use client", is this normal behaviour in nextjs 13

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";


const Home = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

 return <div>test</div>


}
```

Comment: So you literally only have this page and there is a hydration error? Why do you think it's related to Tailwind then? Could you post error details too if there are any?

Comment: there many other pages but "use client" is used only here

Comment: Did you add this `page.tsx` to `tailwind.config.js` content array?